# How to optimally translate enums in the smallest amount of code?

Tags: c++, performance, enums, translation, adapter

It's often the case that you have 2 enums that are equivalent but numbered differently, and you need functions to translate elements from the first enum to elements of the second and the reverse. This is usually really tedious to code, and anytime a new element is added you have to make sure to add the pairing both to the converting and to the reverse-converting function (it violates [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

What's the least error prone way to do this that still generates efficient code? I mention the efficient part because you could just make a bunch of pairs and put them in std::maps if runtime lookups weren't an issue. I'd prefer something that's as performant as manually writing big switch statements going from one enum value to the other.

With some boost preprocessor magic or some template hackery I'm sure you could come up with something where you write a list of pairs and the converting and reverse-converting functions are generated, but I'm not sure which approach to prefer or why. Both methods have a reputation for slow compile times and difficult to diagnose compile errors. Or maybe some other approach entirely?

Comment: So "often the case" that I don't think I've ever needed to do it, in over 25 years of C and C++ programming.

Comment: That's strange... you've never needed to translate between two C libraries that have some overlapping subset of functionality? Or an 'interface' enum and an 'implementation' enum with additional members that needed translating between? Or one enum that maps to how stuff comes off a socket and another enum for how your app expects things to be?

Comment: Can you give an example of how they are numbered differently.  Is the bulk of the set the same order and just offset, or are they re arranged etc.

Comment: They are at an offset *and* rearranged. Simply adding an offset will not work.

Comment: @Neil: See my comment on Dan Olson's answer for an example of how this can happen.

Answer (score 3):

As Neil said, I never faced the problem myself. I have faced the issue with codesets though (ie mapping from a string to an enum, and back).

My first reaction is epidermic: DRY.

As you noted, maintaining two enums and the translation takes time, so it's better to refactor and use only one.

My second reaction would be to try and remove the enum. I don't like enums. Perhaps I'll appreciate them with the upcoming C++0x, but as it stands they're more trouble than they are worth in my mind. I prefer smart objects, with categories, etc...

But then, the problem itself is amusing I guess. So if you like to deal with this messy situation, I might as well try to ease your burden.

Templates can't do much here. I've used them for range checking on enums and for string conversion (back and forth) and iterations, but that's all they can do. However as you suspected it's possible with some "subtle" application of Boost.Preprocessor.

What you'd like to write:

```
DEFINE_CORRESPONDING_ENUMS(Server, Client,
  ((Server1, 1, Client1, 6))
  ((Server2, 2, Client2, 3))
  ((Common1, 4, Common1, 4))
  ((Common2, 5, Common2, 5))
  ((Server3, 7, Client3, 1))
);
```

And we would like it to generate:

```
struct Server
{
  enum type { Server1 = 1, Server2 = 2, Common1 = 4, Common2 = 5, Server3 = 7 };
};

struct Client
{
  enum type { Client1 = 6, Client2 = 3, Common1 = 4, Common2 = 5, Client3 = 1 };
};

Server::type ServerFromClient(Client::type c)
{
  switch(c)
  {
  case Client1: return Server1;
  //...
  default: abort();
  }
}

Client::type ClientFromServer(Server::type s)
{
  //...
}
```

The good news is, this is possible. I could even do it, though I'll probably let you work on it a bit ;)

Here are some explanations:

- The third element of the macro is a sequence. A sequence is of unbounded size.
- Each element of the sequence is a 4-tuple. You need to know its size in advance, thus the repetition for `Common`. If you used a sequence instead, you could deal with a variable number of elements (for example to avoid repeating the common...) but it would make things much more complicated
- You'll need to look at `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOREACH`, it'll be the basic operation here.
- Don't forget `BOOST_PP_CAT` to handle concatenation of tokens.
- on `gcc` the `-E` option yields the preprocessor output, it may come handy...
- don't forget comments and how to use in the file, your colleagues will hate you otherwise

Comment: Unrelated: names ending in `_t` are reserved.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: ah crap! I only knew of `*__*` and `_[A-Z]*` :/ I'll just remove the typedefs then.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?  Not tested, but it should work.

(Standard warnings about premature optimizations and the need for profiling apply; a std::map lookup may not be that bad, a giant switch table may not be that good.)

enums-impl.h:

```
// No include guard.
DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(EGA_BRIGHT_RED, 12, HTML_RED, 0xff0000)
DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(EGA_BRIGHT_BLUE, 9, HTML_BLUE, 0x0000ff)
DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(EGA_BRIGHT_GREEN, 10, HTML_GREEN, 0x00ff00)
DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(EGA_BLACK, 0, HTML_BLACK, 0x000000)
```

enums.cpp:

```
enum EgaColorType {
#define DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(name1, value1, name2, value2) name1 = value1,
#include "enums-impl.h"
#undef DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR
};

enum HtmlColorType {
#define DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(name1, value1, name2, value2) name2 = value2,
#include "enums-impl.h"
#undef DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR 
};

HtmlColorType ConvertEgaToHtml(EgaColorType c) {
switch (c) {
#define DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(name1, value1, name2, value2) case name1: return name2;
#include "enums-impl.h"
#undef DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR
default: assert(false);
}

EgaColorType ConvertHtmlToEga(HtmlColorType c) {
switch (c) {
#define DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR(name1, value1, name2, value2) case name2: return name1;
#include "enums-impl.h"
#undef DEFINE_ENUM_PAIR
default: assert(false);
}
```

Comment: That's basically boost preprocessor magic except reinventing boost preprocessor. Give it a look, it's a lot less ugly than doing X macros yourself: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: You wanted a solution that avoids the slow compile times and difficult-to-diagnose errors of Boost.Preprocessor.  This solution does so.  Boost.Preprocessor is a good tool, and I've used it before, I'm just not convinced that its complexity and overhead are justified in this case.

Comment: Err, AFAICT this is the same technique Boost.Preprocessor uses internally; I don't see how this would be any faster to compile.

Comment: Boost.Preprocessor uses the same techniques internally, but to present its nice interface, it relies on large numbers of header files, hundreds of macro definitions, expansions of expansions of expansions, etc.  I've seen Boost.Preprocessor macros that take tens of thousands of steps to fully expand.  I doubt that what you're trying to do (as outlined in @Matthieu M.'s answer) would be quite so bad, but I doubt it would be as fast as simply including a file a few times, either.

Answer (score 2):

Why won't a lookup table work?  Why are you forced to use this gigantic switch statement??

Comment: A lookup table would work fine if you could generate a bidirectional one that was const. Otherwise you're paying a runtime cost for information that is known at compile time.

Comment: So initialize the lookup table at program startup; a one-time startup-only runtime cost should be negligible.  Or generate a const lookup table plus the enum definitions from a script if you want to avoid all runtime costs.

Comment: You mean "bidirectional" as in there's two of them?

Answer (score 1):

If the enumeration ranges are relatively dense (rather than being used as bitmap indicators), you can just use an array to do the mapping. You let the compiler figure out the array length and then you can assert if the length isn't what you want. You might even be able to static_assert it, I'm not sure. Since you're using arrays, the conversion should be constant time, and possibly better than a switch if the compiler doesn't generate a jump table internally. Note that this code is totally untested.

```
enum A
{
    MIN_A = 1,
    A_ATT_1 = 1,
    A_ATT_2 = 2,
    A_ATT_3 = 3,
    LAST_A
};

enum B
{
    MIN_B = 2
    B_ATT_2 = 2,
    B_ATT_1 = 4,
    B_ATT_3 = 5,
    LAST_B
};

B A_to_B[] =
{
    B_ATT_1,
    B_ATT_2,
    B_ATT_3
};

// Somewhere that will always run, as desired:
assert(LAST_A - MIN_A == sizeof(A_to_B) / sizeof(A_to_B[0]);

B from_A(A in)
{
    B ret = A_to_B[in - MIN_A];
    assert(ret != LAST_B);
    return ret;
}

A B_to_A[] =
{
    A_ATT_2,
    LAST_A,
    A_ATT_1,
    A_ATT_3
};

// Somewhere that will always run, as desired:
assert(LAST_B - MIN_B == sizeof(B_to_A) / sizeof(B_to_A[0]);

A from_B(B in)
{
    A ret = B_to_A[in - MIN_B];
    assert(ret != LAST_A);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always try to make a function (in the sense of mathematical function, not programming function), that translates the number of one enum to the other. But this function would change every time you add elements, though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using two enums.

There's not much difference between these:

```
enum FirstSet { A=4, B=6, C=8, D=5 };
enum SecondSet { E=2, F=5, G=5, H=1 };
```

and this:

```
enum OneEnum { A, B, C, D };
enum TwoEnum { E, F, G, H };
int FirstSet[] = { 4, 6, 8, 5 };
int SecondSet[] = { 2, 5, 5, 1 };
```

The number of accesses that need changing may be prohibitive, but this is a bit better than an O(n) lookup every time you want to convert.

Comment: Unfortunately it's out of my hands. Consider an API that works based on the user passing in values from an enum, EnumA. Originally, the API is implemented with a backend that uses EnumA. Later on, you decide to use a different implementation that uses an entirely different enum internally, EnumB. To maintain backwards compatibility, you need to be able to translate EnumA<->EnumB.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but solveable with modern C++.

You create an `constexpr std::array` of enum-`pair`s. Then you search in these arrays (C++20: `find_if`, C++17 manual loop). This is also `constexpr`.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

enum class E1
{
    E1V1,
    E1V2,
    E1V3,
    E1V4,
    E1V5,
    E1V6,
    E1V7,
    E1V8,
    E1V9,
    E1V0,
};
enum class E2
{
    E2V1 = 77,
    E2V2,
    E2V3,
    E2V4,
    E2V5,
    E2V6 = 1022,
    E2V7,
    E2V8,
    E2V9,
    E2V0,
};

static constexpr std::array conv_table
{
    std::pair(E1::E1V1, E2::E2V1),
    std::pair(E1::E1V2, E2::E2V2),
    std::pair(E1::E1V3, E2::E2V3),
    std::pair(E1::E1V4, E2::E2V4),
    std::pair(E1::E1V5, E2::E2V5),
    std::pair(E1::E1V6, E2::E2V6),
    std::pair(E1::E1V7, E2::E2V7),
    std::pair(E1::E1V8, E2::E2V8),
    std::pair(E1::E1V9, E2::E2V9),
    std::pair(E1::E1V0, E2::E2V0)
};

constexpr E1 convertC(E2 e) 
{
    const auto it = std::find_if(
        conv_table.begin(), conv_table.end(), [e](auto pair){return std::get<1>(pair) == e;});
    return std::get<0>(*it);
}

E1 convert(E2 e) 
{
    return convertC(e);
}

constexpr E2 convertC(E1 e)
{
    const auto it = std::find_if(
        conv_table.begin(), conv_table.end(), [e](auto pair){return std::get<0>(pair) == e;});
    return std::get<1>(*it);
}

E2 convert(E1 e)
{
    return convertC(e);
}

int main() {
    assert(E1::E1V1 == convertC(E2::E2V1));
    assert(E1::E1V9 == convert(E2::E2V9));
    return 0;
}
```

In [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8cWzn6s7Y).

Converting literals (`convertC`) is done completely in compile time (first assert does not even generate code), converting dynamic values (`convert`) is a pretty optimal jump table:
[image: computer code of convert]

Enums can be independent (defined in other headers), have gaps or negative values. Works with class enums. No duplication in creating the array.